# Infopath assembly error on publishing a simple workflow by sharepoint designer to sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, assembly-references

I have Sharepoint 2010 Server on windows 7 installed, and i created a simple List Workflow without any infopath form with Sharepoint Designer 2010, and i have Infopath 2010 Designer and Filler and also 2013 installed on my machine.
but when i want to publish this workflow to Sharepoint it gives me the following error:  [image: error generated by Sharepoint Designer 2010 when publishing on Sharepoint]

I checked the assembly folder in windows folder, and mentioned assembly in error image was already there. and i also ran Sharepoint Designer by Administrator privileges but not any difference.
why this happening?
any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You say you have 2013 installed in parallel. InfoPath does not deal well with multiple versions installed on one machine. I'm just guessing, but this could be the reason for the error. Uninstall InfoPath 2013, then do a repair install of Office 2010. This should set IP 2010 as the default IP instance. Then try to publish your workflow again.

Comment: @teylyn: yeah that was it. please post your comment so that i can accept it as answer.  just one more question: should i have infopath installed for creating workflows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you have 2013 installed in parallel. InfoPath does not deal well with multiple versions installed on one machine. I'm just guessing, but this could be the reason for the error. Uninstall InfoPath 2013, then do a repair install of Office 2010. This should set IP 2010 as the default IP instance. Then try to publish your workflow again.